# Remotely Administer Workgroup Computers

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-access

At work, I can remotely administer other computers by first adding my domain account as a local administrator on another computer.  After that, I can use remote registry, computer management, and file sharing (`\\computer\c$`).

How can I setup a remote user to be a local administrator on a simple home network without a domain (just a workgroup)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth noting that if the username and password that is on your local machine is also exactly duplicated on the remote machine, a mechanism called "[passthrough authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102716)" takes place. It works even in workgroups, even though the documentation only mentions domains. It's a cheap and somewhat laborious way to make a "Domain Admin" on a workgroup network.

Comment: +1 I've been wondering what that feature was called for a few weeks now and hadn't gotten around to asking yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is better suited for Superuser, as it concerns the operation of a single PC.

[Administrative shares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share) differ in performance slightly between Windows versions.

In Windows XP, any local user with administrative privileges can access them.  In Vista/7, they are disabled to local users per default.